# Writing a basic shell interpreter that sends commands to other terminal

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, fork, exec

My goal is write a program that the user enters a system command and my code takes that command and runs it in another terminal window without locking the terminal the user entered the command.

For now, what I have is the code that reads the command, `fork()` the pocess and executes the command as a child porcess.

Here is the main shell interpreter:

```
//argv[1] is the path for the command runner binary
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
  char cmd[512];
  pid_t childPID;

  while(1){
      cout << "Enter the command line: ";
      //reads command from user
      cin.getline(cmd, 512,'\n'); 

      //fork the current parent process 
      childPID = fork();            
      cout << "childPID = " << childPID;

      if(childPID == 0){
          //starts a execution of the command runner, passing the user command as argument
          execl(argv[1],argv[1],cmd, (char *) 0); 
      }
      else{
          cout<<"Error on forking parent"<<endl;
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here is is the command executor that leaves in another file witch is called for every command the user enters:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
  system(argv[1]); //runs system command
  cout << endl;
  cout << "Press enter to continue...";
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out a way to open the execution of the command to another terminal. The other thing is that the loop is jumping two times at once, this I think is a bad implementation.

Comment: Use `xterm -e "command"` to run a command in another `xterm` window.

Comment: I tried this, but the new window runs the command very fast and closes, what I need is see the result of the user command on the window and leave the decision of closing it to the user

Comment: `xterm -e "command;read line"` will wait for the user to type something after the command completes.

Comment: You could also use `xterm -e "command; bash"`. This will start a new shell when the command is done, and the user can run additional commands until he's done with the window.

Comment: Or `xterm -e "command; read -n 1 c"` if you want the terminal window to close on any key press (not just enter).

Comment: @Barmar, I added this line you said to  the string of the command, and now it opens a new window but can't run the code. this error is shown when I run `ls`, for example `Error: Failed to execute child process "ls; read"`

Comment: Oops, got the syntax a little wrong. It's `xterm -e bash -c "ls; read"`. See the examples in https://linux.die.net/man/1/xterm

Comment: Got it now. The part that I fork the process is right? because the moment I enter a command and it runs just fine on the other window, before the end of the while iteration, it falls on the else part displaying the error message I put.